# How to pass a closure as a function parameter if it captures variables

Tags: rust, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to work with higher-order functions in Rust. I'm struggling because the parameter function that I want to pass is a closure that captures a value.

This is my first attempt ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70d704e672c7176c2a06f3d105384f39)):

```rust
/// Takes a value, n, doubles it, and then applies the function f
fn double_then_f(n:u64, f: fn(u64) -> u64) -> u64 {
    f(n * 2)
}

fn main() {
    // Simple f closure works just fine
    let example_1 = double_then_f(5, |n| n + 1);
    
    // More realistic closure doesn't work
    let dynamic_value = vec![1, 2, 3].iter().sum::<u64>();
    let example_2 = double_then_f(5, |n| n + dynamic_value);
}
```

This fails to compile with

```
note: expected fn pointer `fn(u64) -> u64`
                 found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:12:38: 12:41]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
```

After reading over the difference between the `Fn` trait and `fn` types, this is my second attempt:

```rust
/// Takes a value, n, doubles it, and then applies the function f
fn double_then_f(n:u64, f: Box<dyn Fn(u64) -> u64>) -> u64 {
    f(n * 2)
}

fn main() {
    // Simple f closure works just fine
    let example_1 = double_then_f(5, Box::new(|n| n + 1));
    
    // More realistic closure doesn't work
    let dynamic_value = vec![1, 2, 3].iter().sum::<u64>();
    let example_2 = double_then_f(5, Box::new(|n| n + dynamic_value));
}
```

This also fails to compile with lifetime-related errors saying that "cast requires that `dynamic_value` is borrowed for `'static`". I guess the cast it is talking about is casing my closure into a trait object?

What can I do to make this code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Fn-traits!

```rust
fn double_then_f<F: Fn(u64) -> u64>(n:u64, f: F) -> u64 {
    f(n * 2)
}

fn main() {
    let example_1 = double_then_f(5, |n| n + 1);
    
    let dynamic_value = vec![1, 2, 3].iter().sum::<u64>();
    let example_2 = double_then_f(5, |n| n + dynamic_value);
}
```